# Deleting headers from request-config instead of flow in MULE 4

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb, mule4

I'm trying to find solution for deleting request headers in MULE 4 by more effective way then actual. 
In request config is possible to have `<http:default-headers />`, but I can't find way to delete headers from here. So I'm deleting headers in flow -> 
like this:

> ```
>     <http:headers>#[attributes.headers -- ["host", "http.headers"]]</http:headers>
> ```

Full version of flow is here:

```
<flow name="WS_name">
<http:listener path="someway/*" config-ref="External_Listener" doc:name="HTTP">
    <http:response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 200]">
        <http:headers>#[vars.outboundHeaders default {}]</http:headers>
    </http:response>
    <http:error-response statusCode="#[vars.httpStatus default 500]">
        <http:body>#[payload]</http:body>
        <http:headers>#[vars.outboundHeaders default {}]</http:headers>
    </http:error-response>
</http:listener>
<http:request method="#[attributes.method]" sendBodyMode="AUTO" config-ref="HTTPS_Request_configuration_proxy" url="#['https://${endpoint.WS_name.host}:${endpoint.WS_name.port}' ++ '${endpoint.WS_name.path}/']">
    <http:headers>#[attributes.headers -- ["host", "http.headers"]]</http:headers>
</http:request>
```

If anyone have better solution, please, share it.

Comment: Do you want to forward the http attributes received in the listener to the request? And just remove host etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I must delete these two headers from attributes, bcs request don't expect them and fail to error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is fine. If you want to do that in the flow outside of the http:request, then you can. All the http:headers expects is a map. So here is an example of using a var:

```
<set-variable variableName="myAttributes" value="#[attributes.headers -- ['host', 'http.headers']]" />

<http:request method="#[attributes.method]" sendBodyMode="AUTO" config-ref="HTTPS_Request_configuration_proxy"
            url="#['https://${endpoint.WS_name.host}:${endpoint.WS_name.port}' +++ '${endpoint.WS_name.path}/']">
            <http:headers>#[vars.myAttributes]</http:headers>
</http:request>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is easy way. My point was primary make flows as thin as I can.. In Mule 3 I used this: `<https:outbound-endpoint address="URL" transformer-refs="remove-http-headers"/>`, but in Mule 4 is only way to put `<http:headers>` inside `<http:request>` as you described? Its 4+ rows instead of 1.. (Yes, plus 1+ rows of setting transformer-refs)

Comment: Yes but you can encapsulate the var in a sub flow and reuse it

Comment: As I see now, I actually using best choice. Thank you - solved.